# ViewPager background changes while scrolling on Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-viewpager

When scrolling a ViewPager, some parts of the views will disappear while scrolling. This only happens in Ice Cream Sandwich.

Here, we have a ViewPager that swipes between the map and some posts. When you start to swipe over to the posts, the background will sometimes disappear. That grey color is the windowBackground color of our theme. This only happens on Ice Cream Sandwich. Has anybody else experienced this?

[image: Here, we have a ViewPager that swipes between a map and the posts.] [image: While swiping, the background disappears]

These screenshots were taken on the emulator, but it happens on the Galaxy Nexus as well.

Comment: What device is this running on? Is it an official ICS release or a community build? HC/ICS are *much* more sensitive to buggy graphics drivers than previous releases and if that's the culprit, these types of bugs can often only be fixed by the GPU vendor. Drivers released before HC/ICS are almost universally not up to the task.

Comment: Those screenshots were taken on the emulator, so I imagine the graphics drivers aren't the culprit. We first noticed it on the Galaxy Nexus.

I'll take a look at the ViewPager code and see what I can find.

Comment: set the background under the map as a fake map? Smells like it stops drawing the map for optimisation reasons